# Magento1.9 customers not able to login

Tags: magento-1.9, login

I moved a friends website to another server and then also changed the domain name . The site seems to work all fine except two issues:
   - When you will out the customer registration form and click submit no success or even error message is shown. Yet when I login to the Magento admin I see the customer row listed??

- When I try to login with the customer email and password the login page is just reloaded no message is shown and also I am not actually logged in??

I looked in the Chrome browser console and see no errors in there. I also can confirm that the customer registration and login worked before it was moved to another server and the domain name changed. I also have no issues accessing the admin panel. So this seems to only be an issue of the login function.

I have the below cookie settings:

Cookie Lifetime box: 86400

Cookie Path: /

Cookie Domain: 
(have this field blank)

I am not sure where to look or how to troubleshoot this? Anyone ever have similar happen to them?

Comment: Take a look at the cookies. Do you see a double frontend cookie at all?

Comment: This happened for me when cookie domain was wrong. instead of / use a proper domain name for the cookie and try again.

Comment: Thank you I added the domain in the cookie domain field and that helped.